# Refresh button image in Ext JS paging toolbar

Tags: extjs

This is pretty straight but I don't know why refresh button is not visible in my Paging toolbar of ext JS. It is there button not visible.

More clearer explanation:

[image]

As clear from the image button is not visible but see this -
[image]

It is there and I am able to click it and is performing required action but not visible. Do anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Please say which exactly version of ExtJS you are using. Did you modify any of CSS files, or modified the paging toolbar class itself? And of course I assume you did check if the image file is in fact in place?

Comment: You should have inspected your icon using browsers' built-in Inspector and tell us the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `refresh.gif` in `/resource/images/default/grid` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug to inspect the element, make sure none of the CSS has been modified, and of course, make sure that the image is where it needs to be.

I'm guessing `refresh.gif` is missing or been moved/renamed.